# ThreadPoolExecutor queues tasks even when active threads is less than pool size

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, kotlin, threadpoolexecutor

I have a fixed ThreadPoolExecutor that I set up like this. `ThreadPoolExecutorWithMetrics` is just a wrapper class around ThreadPoolExecutor that just emits some Prom metrics at fixed time intervals by parsing the result of `ThreadPoolExecutor.toString()` method. As you can see, my threadpool's coresize and max size are 128 and I am using an unbounded queue.

```
    @Provides
    @Inject
    @Singleton
    fun getRepositoryContext(): RepositoryCoroutineContext {
        val repositoryThreadPoolSize = 128
        logger.info { "Repository thread pool size: $repositoryThreadPoolSize" }
        val threadPool = ThreadPoolExecutorWithMetrics(
            corePoolSize = repositoryThreadPoolSize,
            maximumPoolSize = repositoryThreadPoolSize,
            keepAliveTime = 0L,
            unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            workQueue = LinkedBlockingQueue(),
            name = "RepositoryThreadPool",
        ) { runnable ->
            Thread(runnable).also {
                it.name = "RepositoryDispatcher-worker-${it.id}"
                it.isDaemon = false
                it.priority = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 1
            }
        }
        return RepositoryCoroutineContext(threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher())
    }
```

What I am seeing is that the number of active threads is between 5 and 10. So, my service is using lesser than core pool size/max pool size. But, I also see tasks getting queued up. This shouldn't happen because the number of active threads is less than core pool size. According to the docs,

```
If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
```

So, instead of tasks getting queued up, new threads should be created. Why is this not happening? What am I doing wrong in my threadpool set up?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although your code is in Kotlin, it might be relevant to tag Java for this one. Most pure Kotlin users are probably relying more on coroutines than executors so this question might not get much attention without tagging Java.

Comment: "the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing" - that is not the case, since `ThreadPoolExecutor` have already spawned `corePoolSize` threads it does not spawn new ones and expects threads already spawned pick up tasks via `#take` or `#poll`

Comment: I don't think that is true. The docs say the threads are created on-demand. "On-demand construction
By default, even core threads are initially created and started only when new tasks arrive, but this can be overridden dynamically using method prestartCoreThread() or prestartAllCoreThreads(). You probably want to prestart threads if you construct the pool with a non-empty queue." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: your last graph demonstrates the thread pool got saturated - pool size is 128, there is no option to spawn new threads.

Comment: The last graph does not represent the number of threads running. It is the size of the threadpool that is set up. Basically, the output of the threadpool.toString() method is parsed using a regex expression like this: `pool size = (\d*), active threads = (\d*), queued tasks = (\d*), completed tasks = (\d*)`. Here, active threads is what represents the number of threads running.

Comment: I'm afraid you are misinterpreting the output of `ThreadPoolExecutor#toString`: `pool size` is amount of spawned threads, `active threads` is amount of threads currently executing some task, i.e. "busy" threads.

Comment: And ... obviously you won't get more threads concurrently running than there are cores.  Note: if your code is CPU or I/O intensive you won't get any performance benefit in making nos_thread significantly larger than nos_cores.  The hardware limits the performance.